# Animate Tikz does not compile correctly

Tags: tikz-pgf, animate

**tldr** Old version of `pdflatex` compiles to static PDF, newer version compiles correctly -- Overleaf also returns a static PDF.

I was playing around with `animate` and TikZ, but I am unable to compile any animated PDFs. (OS = KDE Neon (Ubuntu 18.04))

As an example: [Animated Set Intersection](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/animated-set-intersection/) (Example, PDF file and source code is all from http://www.texample.net).

When I download the PDF from [here](http://www.texample.net/media/tikz/examples/PDF/animated-set-intersection.pdf), it works perfectly fine.

Edit: Correction. The code I am running is the following from [here](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/animated-set-intersection/) under "A standalone version" section.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{animate}

\usepackage{fp}

% parameterized tikz graphics
\newcommand{\intersect}[1]{%
\def\setA{(0,0) circle (1)}%
\def\setB{(#1,0) circle (1)}%
% define the bounding box
\def\boundb{(-2,2) rectangle (4,-2)}%
%
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw \boundb;
    % intersection
    \begin{scope}
    \clip \setA;
    \fill[black!20] \setB;
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}[even odd rule]% first circle without the second
    \clip \setB \boundb;
    \fill[red!20] \setA;
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}[even odd rule]% first circle without the second
    \clip \setA \boundb;
    \fill[blue!20] \setB;
    \end{scope}
\draw \setA;
\draw \setB;
\node at (-1,0) [left] {$A$};
\node at (#1+1,0) [right] {$B$};
\node at (4,2) [below left] {$A\cap B$};
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Set intersection}
\begin{center}

\begin{animateinline}[autoplay,palindrome]{12}
%first frame, xb=0.0
\gdef\xb{0}% xb initial value
\intersect{\xb}%
%remaining frames, xb=0.1...2.1
\whiledo{\lengthtest{\xb pt < 2.1pt}}{%
    \newframe
    \FPeval{xb}{\xb+0.1}% new xb
    \xdef\xb{\xb}% make \xb global
    \intersect{\xb}%
}%
\end{animateinline}

\end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

When compiling the code with `pdflatex` I get a PDF but it is not animated.

The problem appears to be an outdated version of PdfLaTeX.

I get a static PDF when compiling with PdfLaTeX on my KDE Neon machine (Ubuntu 18.04). Here is the output of `pdflatex --version`

```
pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017/Debian)
kpathsea version 6.2.3
Copyright 2017 Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the pdfTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the pdfTeX source.
Primary author of pdfTeX: Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
Compiled with libpng 1.6.34; using libpng 1.6.34
Compiled with zlib 1.2.11; using zlib 1.2.11
Compiled with poppler version 0.62.0
```

However, when compiling on a machine running Manjaro I get a PDF with animations. The output of `pdflatex --version`:

```
pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019/Arch Linux)
kpathsea version 6.3.1
Copyright 2019 Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the pdfTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the pdfTeX source.
Primary author of pdfTeX: Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
Compiled with libpng 1.6.37; using libpng 1.6.37
Compiled with zlib 1.2.11; using zlib 1.2.11
Compiled with poppler version 0.88.0
```

What the exact difference is, I do not know. But it appears to be not a TeX problem afterall -- sorry.

Comment: Please provide us with more information. Where is the pdf that works from? Which pictures are you using for your animation?

Comment: Though the code example shown in the question uses deprecated practice (`\whiledo` instead of `\multiframe` for loops around parameterized inline graphics), it compiles smoothly on Overleaf and in TeXLive-2020. The downloaded PDF plays in Okular 1.10.1 on Linux and in Acrobat Reader DC.